# What 'exactly' happens when I type a password in a web-browser before the password is sent out of the machine onto the network?

Tags: passwords, password-protection

What happens exactly when I type a password into a password input field in a form in a web-page (e.g the password field of Gmail) and then hit enter.  I want to understand the procedure before the browser sends it out of the local machine onto the network. For example: on the local machine, the web-browser first makes a system call, then the local machine does some processing on the password, and then sends it over the network.  I searched on Google a lot, but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special happens, in general.

A password is just an HTML `<input>` element. It's just a text box.

Answer (score 0):

In most instances, web sites requiring form submitted passwords use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) to encrypt the posted data (including the username and password) back up to the server (if the site doesn't use SSL, then the password would be sent up in cleartext).

**Edit:**
[According to wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), SSL / TLS works at the presentation layer of the OSI, although this [SSL article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) indicates that SSL is in the TCP application layer. AFAIK https is just http working on top of an SSL connection.

As per @John's post, the traditional way of submitting passwords is by providing the user with a form with a username  and password . 
(Full reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html))

```
<form name="input" action="https://somesite/login.asp" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This form data would be posted back to the server, which should then validate the input before checking authentication of username and password (usually by passing one or both fields through a one way hash to ensure that passwords aren't stored cleartext in the database).

From a security point of view

- Although the browser will 'show' asterisks on the password control, the browser still has knowledge of the cleartext password.
- Secure forms method should be POST (method = GET would appear on the querystring)
- The form page itself should have been served via https (since in addition to encryption, the browser verifies the server's certificate against the domain, for expiry, for the certification chain itself)
- and the form action itself should use an https:// url, to ensure that the username and password are encrypted in transit on the way back to the server.

One concept that needs to be made is the reason why the browser doesn't 'hash' or otherwise do some of the authentication checking on the 'client side' of the connection is because the server mustn't ever trust the browser / remote computer - the original full password must be sent by the remote client computer.

Re : Can I hack the password?

Common attacks are

- Keylogging - software which logs user's keystrokes, including usernames and passwords
- Phishing - the attacker presents the user with a site login page which looks like the target login page, the user can be fooled into typing username and password. If the user's configured DNS or LMHosts file is compromised, then the login URL can be made to appear bonafide, even though it is served by the attacker's phishing server.
- XSS attack (e.g. if the login page displays unvalidated user comment posts on the same page) would allow an attacker to inject javascript to hook into any number of events on the page to obtain usernames and passwords
- With weak client validation and some information about the design of server, SQL Injection attacks can be used to either bypass the login entirely, read data from the server database (e.g. obtain all users and passwords if they are stored cleartext), or corrupt or delete data on the server (but this attacks the server, not the browser)

Comment: I don't know if I'd claim most sites send passwords via HTTPS.  They **should** but that doesn't mean they do.  Most big sites do, but there's plenty of smaller sites that may not.

Comment: @nonnb -> so this is what I interpreted : the https works at the highest layer of OSI model i.e Application. So, when I type the password, e.g of gmail, then the web-site will immediately encrypt it in some format. Now this encrypted code is what my local machine can access. The whole purpose of asking is, whether depending on the values in the registers of local machine, can I 'hack' the password? And I know the answer is NO, but I am not really able to pin-point the cause. Please correct me as I am a novice to these concepts.

Comment: I've updated the post :) Would suggest you code up a login page in your favourite language, and use a tool like Fiddler to monitor traffic between browser and server.

Comment: I'm afraid very few sites that ask for username & password use https. Though I agree more should.

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question. I'm very tempted to downvote it. Among other things, you're doing a great job of confusing things by talking about OSI layers.

Comment: In fact, on second thought I have downvoted. If the OP wants to know about end to end processing of passwords, then the OP should ask a second question. The answer to _this_ question is that "nothing happens".